# How do I make a component absolutely unique?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

So this is pissing me off at the moment. According to the Ember documentation a component is reusable, but apparently it is not unique!

So I have spend two days to make a custom date selector component. The component consists of three text inputs (day, month and year) and some additional functionalities that are displayed in popups on focus. But when I have two date selectors in one screen, when I select just one of them, the popups of both date selectors appear.

Now one of these popups contains buttons for all days of a month, 0 to 31. These are added in the template with an {{#each}} helper. Makes sense right? Well, if I have two date selectors, these buttons are added twice to both components, displaying 0-31 and another 0-31.

So, first off all, I'd like to warn everybody. **A component is not unique!** It's a singleton with properties and methods shared by all instances. This is not made clear at all in the Ember documentations. (which sucks anyway since a lot of info is missing)

Second, I'd like to know if someone has a quick fix for this. Is a component the way to go, or should I switch to something else?

Comment: Can you put together an example on http://emberjs.jsbin.com showing the issue you are seeing. Each Ember Component instance should be unique and not share state. If you post a bin I can try to help.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/zateta/4/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is because you are setting the `foo` property on the `FooBarComponent` Class/Prototype, which is shared between all instances.

To achieve what you want you need to set the `foo` property on each `FooBarComponent` instance. One way to do that is to set the `foo` property in the `init` hook like below.

```
App.FooBarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super();
    this.set('foo', Ember.A(["bar"]));
  },

  actions: {
    onClick: function() {
      this.get('foo').pushObject("whatever");
    }
  }
});
```

You can see a working bin here: http://jsbin.com/leyut/1/edit

Comment: good find. I thought this was a bug. Some more information over here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3908